# Why is my method incorrect for adding two floating point numbers such as 5.0 and 3.0 according to ieee754?

Tags: floating-point, addition, ieee-754

---

5 in binary is `101`

3 in binary is `11`

exponent for 5 is `127 + 2 = 129 10000001`

exponent for 3 is `127 + 1 = 128 10000000`

mantissa for 5 is `01000000000000000000000`

mantissa for 3 is `10000000000000000000000`

equalize the exponent `129 - 128 = 1`

shift mantissa for 3 to the right by 1

```
01000000000000000000000
```

add both mantissa

```
01000000000000000000000+01000000000000000000000 =

10000000000000000000000
```

**result:**

```
sign = 0

exponent = 10000001

mantissa = 10000000000000000000000
```

Comment: The significand for 5 is (as a binary numeral) 1.01000000000000000000000. The significand for 3 is 1.10000000000000000000000. When these are encoded into the bit fields of an IEEE-754 format, the last 23 bits are put into the significand field, and 1 bit is represented via the exponent. The field that contains these 23 bits is NOT the entire significand; that is just part of the encoding. Another bit is determined by the exponent field. When you shift the 23 bits 10000000000000000000000 for 3 right to align them with the bits for 5, you must include the leading 1, so the result is 110000000…

Answer (score 2):

> Why is my method incorrect for adding two floating point numbers such as 5.0 and 3.0 according to ieee754?

The implied most significant bit of the significand is not taken into account.

> mantissa for 5 is 01000000000000000000000  (OP's incorrect claim)
> mantissa for 3 is 10000000000000000000000  (OP's incorrect claim)

No.  Those are the encoding, not the value.

The mantissa, more properly call the significand, is

```
5 is 1.01000000000000000000000 expo 129
3 is 1.10000000000000000000000 expo 128
```

Adding those

```
 10.1000000000000000000000  expo 128
  1.10000000000000000000000 expo 128
--------------------------
100.00000000000000000000000 expo 128
```

Rounding that to 1+23 bits

```
1.00000000000000000000000 expo 130
```

or 8.0f

Comment: @omskiski the 26 bit sum was "100.00000000000000000000000 expo 128".  The next step is to round that to something that fits in 24 bits: "1.00000000000000000000000 expo 130".

Comment: Just to clarify my understanding the exponent for 5 which is 129 is decreased because its fractional value is less than 3. 0.1 < .10 and because of this it is shifted to the right  by the difference of the exponents(1 being the case). I don't understand the rounding to 1 + 23 is it because to keep the implicit 1 intact or is the 1 for 1 + 23 due to the difference of the exponents 129 - 128.

Comment: "exponent for 5 which is 129 is decreased because its fractional value is less than 3." --> No.  The fractional values are irrelevant.  1.01000000000000000000000 expo 129 is re-written as `10.1000000000000000000000 expo 128 so the addition can add values of the same units.  You can don't add 1 pound to 2 pence to get 3.  Needs common units.  100 pence + 2 p --> 102 p.

Comment: @omskiski After the addition, the sum is 100.00000000000000000000000 expo 128.  That is more than 24 digits of a `float` significand.  So we round to the best 24 digits answer, which is 1.00000000000000000000000 expo 130.  In this case, that is simply lopping off the right most 2 zero bits.